# Pulling lastwritetime from files across share drives

Tags: powershell, foreach, get-childitem

The goal is to find files across share drives that have a lastwritetime of this year.

```
$creds = Read-Host "Input username"
$dirs = get-WmiObject -class Win32_Share -computer fileshare.whatever -Credential $creds
ForEach($dir in $dirs){
(gci -Recurse  |?{$_.LastWriteTime -like "*2023*"}).count
}
```

The `$dirs` variable works and shows 40 shares and that part is correct.
When the `ForEach` runs, I just get the number `20` printed 40 times.

If I run simply `(gci "\\fileshare\firstsharefolder\" -Recurse  |?{$_.LastWriteTime -like "*2023*"}).count` I get the correct count of items.

Can someone please show me where I made my mistake?  I tend to struggle with the `ForEach` loop.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Should be : gci $_ -Recurse

Comment: You forgot to use `$dir` in your call to `Get-ChildItem`: `($dir | Get-Child-Item | ? ....).Count`

Comment: @jdweng I get the same result as before.

Comment: Try replace ".count" with : | Foreach { Write-Host "FileName = " $_.Value}

Comment: @jdweng I get "FileName =" a few thousand times.

Comment: You are recuring twice.  The method get-WmiObject is getting each child and gci is getting each child.  Remove the Recursive from gci -Recurse

Comment: @jdweng I now get all 9's

Comment: What does that mean?  Are you getting correct results?  Looks like each directory has nine files that match the search pattern.

Comment: @jdweng well one directory I know for sure has 4 and one has 1819, so no.  I think it just prints the last count for the last $dir even though it's not that individual directory's result.

Comment: Instead of count use Measure-Object : gci | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -like "*2023*"} | Measure-Object